# Find all htaccess files on server

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I'm looking for a Linux command to go through all the directories on my server and find all .htaccess files. The output would be a list of all those files with full path, creation/modification date and filesize.

Comment: Server fault maybe, not a programming question

Comment: The linux shell is Turing complete so it technically is a "programming question" haha

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`find / -name ".htaccess" -print`

Replace `/` with the root folder you like to start searching, in case you don't want to search the whole file system.

Wikipedia has an article about [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find), which also links to its man page.

Comment: Note that, if you start from the root directory / , you'll need to run the find command with root privileges so that you're able to read all subdirectories on the system.

Answer (score 7):

It's easy with the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command.

```
find / -name .htaccess -exec ls -l {} \;
```

This will print the name, and the file details according to `ls -l`.  Note that this is starting the search under `/`, which may take a long time.  You might want to specify a different folder to search.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way to achieve:

locate .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

find -name .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as

```
ls -l $(locate .htaccess)
```

if `updatedb` has run recently.

Comment: Not every server has `mlocate` installed in it.